# change behavior of CSS -transition property

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm using CSS transition property, to animate webpage. Basically what I got so far is: when I am in the home page ( `class="content"` only ) and I click on 'About Me' link (`class="secondary"`), about me page false down in the good way, but if I than go to another link with `class="secondary"`, 'About Me' page will first go up and than another page will false down. And I don't want this behavior. I want another page with `class="secondary"` just false in front of the previous one.

I was trying to do my best on  [http://jsfiddle.net/FMRBf/2](http://jsfiddle.net/FMRBf/2/)

## HTML

```
 <li><a href="#home" id="nav-home">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#another-page" id="nav-portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
 <li><a href="#about" id="nav-about">About Me</a></li>
</br>
<div id="home" class="content">
   <h2>Home</h2>
</div>

<div id="about" class="secondary">
   <div class="content">
    <h2>About Me</h2>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="another-page" class="secondary">
   <div class="content">
    <h2>Another Secondary Page</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.content {
  background-color: rgba(255,233,0,0.8);
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.secondary {
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 98%;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow-y: auto; 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    margin-top: -100%;

  -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all .8s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .8s ease-in;
    transition: all .8s ease-in;
}
.secondary:target {
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(255,233,0,1);
}
```

Comment: Please show your CSS and HTML as part of the question

Comment: what do you mean about false down?

Comment: I mean that it start moving from top to bottom.